# Derived date calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am currently entering data into a SQL Server database using SSIS. The plan is for it to do this each week but the day that it happens may differ depending on when the data will be pushed through.

I use SSIS to grab data from an Excel worksheet and enter each row into the database (about 150 rows per week). The only common denominator is the date between all the rows. I want to add a date to each of the rows on the day that it gets pushed through. Because the push date may differ I can't use the current date I want to use a week from the previous date entered for that row.

But because there are about 150 rows I don't know how to achieve this. It would be nice if I could set this up in SQL Server where every time a new set of rows are entered it adds 7 days from the previous set of rows. But I would also be happy to do this in SSIS.

Does anyone have any clue how to achieve this? Alternatively, I don't mind doing this in C# either.

Comment: Adds 7 days where? Do you have a column for tracking the date, in addition to your other columns?

Comment: Hi Shree. I am wanting to add a column for the date and insert the date into that using whatever method works.

Comment: So am I right to say that you want to get the latest date of data entry for the data in your table, add 7 days to that and then insert all the new rows with that date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do what you want:

1. Create a column for tracking the data entry date in your target table.
2. Add an Execute SQL Task before the Data Flow Task. This task will retrieve the latest data entry date + 7 days. The query should be something like:

   `select dateadd(day,7,max(trackdate)) from targettable`
3. Assign the SQL result to a package variable.
4. Add a Derived Column Transformation between your Source and Destination components in the Data Flow Task. Create a dummy column to hold the tracking date and assign the variable to it.
5. When you map the Excel to table in a Data Flow task, map the dummy column created earlier to the tracking date column. Now when you write the data to DB, your tracking column will have the desired date.

[Derived Column Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190169.aspx)

Comment: I will give this a go now

Comment: I can't seem to get the variable into the table. I have created it using your SQL statement but in my data flow I don't know how to put it into the column

Comment: I think you can add it in the mapping columns. I don't have SSIS installed now so can't provide a screenshot, but the idea is to pass it at the source column side in the mapping tab.

Comment: Yeah I can't see where. Argghh

Comment: @Danrex Sorry, realised you will need to add it as a derived column first. Updating my answer.

Comment: I'm having issues but probably not to do with the informtion you gave me. I am managing to get the correct date in a variable but can't seem to get that into the data table.

Comment: My problem was I was trying to do a Union All on a Derived Column that wasn't modifying an existing column. But now it works thanks